# Load System.String result into Div (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

From what I understand, `$.load` in jQuery injects HTML into an element (e.g. a div). However, what I want to do is to send a string to a div via a MVC controller action.

```
Public Function Stream() As String
    Dim streamPath As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("LiveStreamPath")
    Dim dataStream As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(streamPath)

    dataStream = dataStream.Replace(vbNewLine, "<br/>")

    Return dataStream
End Function
```

This is within `HomeController` and `Global.asax` has the URL mapped to /Home/Stream and indeed going to this location manually shows a page with the text located at LiveStreamPath. However, I want to use another View to view this information in a div.

The jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#testmonitor').load('Home/Stream');
    });
</script>
```

The view itself is nothing special, just `<div id="testmonitor"></div>`.

I'm fairly certain the issue lies in my jQuery. How can I get the script to load a string result into `testmonitor`?

EDIT: The URL of the view shows up as ~/Home/MonitorTests?Length=4. A quick google search showed that the Length property being appended means that a string is actually being passed to the view.

Comment: If the controller Home/Stream is dependent on the view, shouldn't you load the view in the controller instead? Now it seems you are loading the content of Home/Stream into a non-existing element :)

Comment: Nothing happens, actually. Also, what's the hole? I'm not familiar with writing code that prevents against XSS.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen The file at LiveStreamPath is actually constantly changing. I want to be able to display the changes live to the user using a timer function (which I will implement as soon as the div can display the text first), so that's why I am using jQuery as opposed to directly loading the file into my view.

Answer (score 1):

You're using a relative path, which won't work unless you're in the root.

Change it to `.load('/Home/Stream')`.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue. I suspect it has more to do with what the controller is actually returning.